# Spring boot validate multiple object from map

Tags: validation, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to validate more than one entity before create or update. I have done these simply with custom validator in Grails. I'm wondering is there any way to do custom validator in spring which will take constraints (@NotNull, @Size etc) from entity.

Example entities:
**Employee:**

```
@Entity
class Employee{
    @NotNull
    String firstName

    @NotNull
    String lastName

    @NotNull
    Date dob

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "contact_id", nullable = true)
    Contact contact
}
```

**Contact:**

```
@Entity
class Contact{
    @NotNull
    String mobile

    @NotNull
    String email
}
```

Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
ResponseEntity create(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> payload) {
    Employee employee = new Employee()
    Contact contact = new Contact()
    //assign some properties before validation
    //validate employee and contact
    // create employee and contact
}
```

**JSON request:**

```
{
  "employee": {
    "firstName": "abc",
    "lastName": "def",
    "contact": {
      "mobile": "9876543210",
      "email": "email@example.com"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to do custom validation like, if contact object is present, then validate, its properties. If DOB is greater than particular date, then expect some properties etc.

Comment: You can use  [Spring’s Validator interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validator).

But I am wondering why do I wanna validate One Entity before another. You can validate beans independently and while persisting those in database you can validate if every entity you wanna persist has data.
Methods annotated with `@Transactional` will be helpful here.